# connecting twitter API to R with rtweet package

Tags: r, twitter-oauth, api-key, rtweet

I donwloaded the rtweet package in r as there are more functions than tweetR, but the output keeps giving me an error saying that "auth" is not found. I am not sure how to input the api key and token because of the new update. Anyone know the code? I entered the tokens and keys the twitter api gave me but can't figure out how to get it to sync/run.

```
library(rtweet)
install.packages("ROAuth")
library(ROAuth)

## authenticate via access token
app = "statskenyon"
consumer_key = "my key"
consumer_secret = "consumer secret"
acess_token = "access token"
access_secret = "access secret"

auth <- rtweet_app("bearer token")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the previous version of rtweet, after You have to save your tokens to an R object first.

```
    your_token_name <- create_token(app = "statskenyon",
          consumer_key = "my key",
          consumer_secret = "consumer secret",
          access_token = "access token",
          access_secret = "access secret",
          set_renv = TRUE
        )
```

Then use it in a post_status().

```
post_tweet(
  status = "my first rtweet #rstats",
  token = your_token_name
)
```

In newer version, instead of using

```
auth <- rtweet_app("bearer token")
```

I suggest You to use rtweet_bot() function, since from your code you only have 4 keys.

```
your_new_token_name <- rtweet::rtweet_bot(
  api_key =    "my key",
  api_secret = "consumer secret",
  access_token =    "access token",
  access_secret =   "access secret"
)
```

Then use it to post a status message

```
rtweet::post_tweet(
  status = "your_status_message",
  token = your_new_token_name
)
```